# Typescript: union of index signature object and other type results in error

Tags: typescript

I would like to be able to type **prop** as both index signature object or just a number. Example of code to reproduce the problem:

```
interface ITest {
  prop?: { [key: string]: number } | number
}

const obj: ITest = {}

// Property 'test' does not exist on type 'number | { [key: string]: number; }'.
console.log(obj.prop.test)
```

Comment: added an code snippet in my answer. hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an property type either an obj OR an primitive type OR undefined.
while setting the property is easy. you need to check the type of "prop" before reading it as shown in the below code.

```
 interface ITest {
   prop?: { [key: string]: number } | number
}

//const obj: ITest = { prop: { "age": 22 } };
const obj: ITest = { prop: 55 };

if (typeof obj.prop === 'number') {
      console.log(obj.prop);
}
else {
   Object.keys(obj.prop).forEach(element => {
      console.log(obj.prop[element]);
   });
}
```

based on the comments, following is the ES2015 code,generated from the above ts code, I do not see the error which you are reporting, Am I missing something?

```js
const obj = { prop: { "age": 22 } };
//const obj: ITest = { prop: 55 };
if (typeof obj.prop === 'number') {
    console.log(obj.prop);
}
else {
    Object.keys(obj.prop).forEach(element => {
        console.log(obj.prop[element]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work with the following error:  error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'number | { [key: string]: number; }' has no index signature.

Another problem is that I'm trying to augment Vue options type for vue-graphql-loader and would like to avoid any type checks in components, because it's too verbose and makes component code very difficult. I will update question soon to provide better details of the exact use case.

Comment: The problem is here: https://github.com/zephraph/vue-graphql-loader/blob/master/src/handler.ts I just wanted to contrib. 
I need to augment Vue component options, so later I can access graphql queries like that: `this.$options.query.myQuery` (wtihout any checks). 

It has the following interface because it also supports anonymous queries:

`import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';

interface GraphQLComponentOptions extends ComponentOptions<Vue> {
  query?: DocumentNode | { [key: string]: DocumentNode };
}`

Apology for too much details, but I don't know how to explain better.

Comment: I see your point but I am not sure, typescript allows that without doing an typecheck.

Comment: I suggested author to create another property that will have access to only non-anonymous queries, so it will use only index signature as type, without union. Thanks.